# Documents all from a single shard if using a wildcard

Tags: elasticsearch, sharding

If I have an index with multiple shards and run a query like this:

```
GET my-index/_search
{
  "explain": true,
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "bar"
    }
  }
}
```

I will get a nice property in each hit, like this: `"_shard" : "[my-index][1]",`

If I change that query to include a wildcard though (eg, `"query": "bar*"`), the shard always returns as `[my-index][0]`. I have even done a query with a unique identifier to ensure I am looking at the same document. Even then, the shard will seem to change as soon as a wildcard is used.

What is the explanation for this and are there any repercussions?

Comment: Are the results you get accurate?

Comment: yes, the actual documents in the `hits` seem to be accurate.

Comment: So what's the point of knowing from which shards the results are coming?

Comment: just curious. i find it to be very surprising behavior and it might be a sign that i have somehow configured shards, replicas, etc. incorrectly.

Comment: Can you tell the difference of the `max_score` value between both queries?

Comment: yes. the non-wildcard query will have some floating point score, like 10.123. as soon as i add a wildcard, it is just 1.0.